# Highlight the selected item with black color and already selected item with green color

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, python-3.7

I am unable to highlight the selected items in my menu bar. I got problem in version of code. I just want to highlight the present selected items with black color and already selected item in green color.for e.g. Highlight the image named Rice in my interface.

I have tried to add this but i only got code of previous version due to which i got more errors.

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets

count = 0
width,height=1300,700
oneUnit = (width+height)/100

class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        # ---------Window settings --------------------------------
        self.width,self.height = 1300,700
        # //for using in full screen
        # width = mainWindow.frameGeometry().width()
        # height = mainWindow.frameGeometry().height()
        self.setGeometry(0, 0,width,height)
        self.setWindowTitle("Interface")
        #---------content that are displayed in window
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.userInfoArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.centralwidget)
        self.userInfoArea.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1, 1, width*.7 -2, 
      height*.15 -2))
        self.mainRight = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.centralwidget)
        self.mainRight.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(width*.7, 1, width*.3 -2 , 
      height-2))
        self.billingArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.centralwidget)
        self.billingArea.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(width*.7 , height*.15, 
      width*.3 -2, height*.65 -2))
        self.mainArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.centralwidget)
        self.mainArea.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1, height*.15 +1, width*.7 -2, 
      height*.85 -2))
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1, height*.15 +1, width*.7 
    -3, 
    height*.85 -3))
        self.lunchTab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.lunchTab.setObjectName("lunchTab")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.lunchTab, "Lunch/Snacks")
        self.drinkTab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.drinkTab.setObjectName("drinkTab")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.drinkTab, "Drinks")


        self.paybillBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Pay Bill",self.mainRight)
        self.showBtn(self.paybillBtn,self.mainRight,.65,.815,100,100)
        #showingImage function contains images arranged in grid format
        self.showingImage()

        self.add = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Add",self.mainRight)
        self.add.clicked.connect(self.Add)
        self.add.setObjectName("add_button")
        self.add.price = "Rs. 80"
        self.add.quantity = 0
        '''
        button = self.mainRight.findChildren(QtWidgets.QPushButton)
        print("list")
        print(button[1].setObjectName("changed"))
        print("lsit finis  ")
        '''
        self.grid = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.billingArea)
        self.grid.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 240, 350, 440))

        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.billingArea)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(5,5, 380, 440))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = 
      QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")

        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.show()

    def showBtn(self,obj,frame,xPos,yPos,width,height):
        mainR_width,mainR_height = 
    frame.frameGeometry().width(),frame.frameGeometry().height()
         obj.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(mainR_width*xPos, mainR_height*yPos, 
    width, height))

    def Add(self):
        global count
        source = self.sender()
        source.quantity += 1
        frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 369, 39))
        frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Plain)
        frame.setObjectName("frame")
        minusButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("-",frame)
        minusButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 10, 21, 23))
        minusButton.setObjectName("minusButton")
        plusButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("+",frame)
        plusButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 10, 21, 23))
        plusButton.setObjectName("plusButton")
        deleteButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("x",frame)
        deleteButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 10, 21, 23))
        deleteButton.setObjectName("deleteButton")
        foodLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(str(source.objectName()),frame)
        foodLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 100, 13))
        foodLabel.setObjectName("foodLabel")
        priceLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(str(source.price),frame)
        priceLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 10, 47, 13))
        priceLabel.setObjectName("priceLabel")
        quantityLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(str(source.quantity),frame)
        quantityLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 10, 16, 16))
        quantityLabel.setObjectName("quantityLabel")

        '''
        frames = self.verticalLayoutWidget.findChildren(QtWidgets.QFrame)
        print("frames",frames,"frames")
        for frame in frames:
            labels = frame.findChildren(QtWidgets.Qlabel)
            print(labels)
            for label in labels:
                if label.text() == source.objectName():
                    print("something")
        '''

        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(frame)
        count += 1

    def Button(self):
        sender = self.sender()
        print(sender.text())

    def showingImage(self):
        imgWi,imgHi=self.width*.12,self.height*.2
        imgX, imgY = oneUnit, 2*oneUnit
        self.image1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Rice Set", self.lunchTab)
        self.image1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(imgX , imgY, imgWi,imgHi))
        self.image1.setObjectName("Rice Set")
        self.image1.price = "Rs. 80"
        self.image1.quantity = 0
        self.image1.clicked.connect(self.Add)
        imgX = imgX + imgWi + oneUnit

        self.image2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Curd", self.lunchTab)
        self.image2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(imgX , imgY, imgWi,imgHi))
        self.image2.setObjectName("Curd")
        self.image2.price = "Rs. 25"
        self.image2.quantity = 0
        self.image2.clicked.connect(self.Add)
        imgX = imgX + imgWi + oneUnit

        self.image3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("image3", self.lunchTab)
        self.image3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(imgX , imgY, imgWi,imgHi))
        imgX = imgX + imgWi + oneUnit

        self.image4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("image4", self.lunchTab)
        self.image4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(imgX , imgY, imgWi,imgHi))
        imgX = imgX + imgWi + oneUnit

        self.image5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("image5", self.lunchTab)
        self.image5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(imgX , imgY, imgWi,imgHi))
        imgX = oneUnit
        imgY = imgY + imgHi + oneUnit*5

        self.image6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("image6", self.lunchTab)
        self.image6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(imgX , imgY, imgWi,imgHi))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I expect the selected item to be highlighted.

Comment: I want to highlight the items inside the function def showingImage(self) after selection of item. @eyllanesc

Comment: What do you mean by *already selected item with green color* ?, from what I understand you want the current selected element to be black and the previously selected elements are green. I am right?

Comment: I want to highlight the selected items like rice and curd in my case.If u can then help me.@eyllanesc

Answer (score 0):

Just to understand well you need to change the color of button already selected in green and the current selected black ? 
You may use CSS for that. By changing the name of your object when you click on it. For example:

```css
#element_selected {
background-color:green;
}

#current_element {
background-color:black;
}
```

Thanks to this :

```py
def setCSS(self,css_filename):
        css = open(css_filename,'r')
        self.setStyleSheet(css.read())
```

You will be able to add to your mainwindow your CSS. Moreover, if you use this method, you will need to refresh your CSS after changing the object name of one button. That's why it's usefull to have this method!